# A simple way of calculating the sum of this Sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

There is a sequence:

$1+5+17+53+161+...+354293+1062881$

And the total value of this sequence has to be calculated.

I know that $a_{n} = 3a_{n-1} + 2$

But, how could I find the sum of this recursive sequence?

Please help me here. Thanks

Comment: The formula you wrote is wrong, you can check for yourself!

Comment: I'm sorry its 3*a(n-1)

Comment: Hint: $\;a_n+1=3(a_{n-1}+1)\,$ means $\,a_n+1\,$ is a geometric progression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a_n = 3 a_{n - 1} + 2$ then $a_n + 1 = 3(a_{n - 1} + 1)$.

Let $b_n = a_n + 1$. Then $b_0 = 2$ and $b_n = 3 b_{n - 1}$. Then $b_n = 2 \cdot 3^n$. Then $a_n = 2 \cdot 3^n - 1$.

Now setting $1062881 = a_n = 2 \cdot 3^n - 1$, we see that $n = 12$.

So we are looking for $\sum\limits_{i = 0}^{12} 2 \cdot 3^n - 1 = (2 \cdot \sum\limits_{i = 0}^{12} 3^n) - 13$.

Using the geometric series formula, we have $\sum\limits_{i = 0}^n 3^n = \frac{3^{n + 1} - 1}{3 - 1}$. So $\sum\limits_{i = 0}^{12} 3^n = \frac{3^{13} - 1}{2}$. So $2 \cdot \sum\limits_{i = 0}^{12} 3^n = 3^{13} - 1.$

So the sum is $3^{13} - 14 = 1594309$.

Comment: This is (probably) correct. That said, I am disappointed to see answers to questions where the OP asks "do this for me", showing no effort of their own.

Comment: @EthanBolker I wouldn't say no work - they did come up with the recurrence. But yes, I guess I should be more conscientious about that in the future.

Comment: Thank you @MarkSaving. This is Correct

Answer (score 1):

I see this has been already answered but I'll post this anyway for future reference. We can identify a closed form for $a_k$:
$$a_0=a_0$$
$$a_1=3a_0+2$$
$$a_2=3^2a_0+3\cdot 2+2$$
$$a_3=3^3a_0+3^2\cdot2+3\cdot 2+2$$
$$a_4=3^4a_0+3^3\cdot2+3^2\cdot 2+3\cdot 2+2$$
$$...$$
$$a_k=3^ka_0+2\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}3^j$$
The sum up to arbitrary $n$ is thus
$$s_n=\sum_{k=0}^na_k=a_0\sum_{k=0}^n3^k+2\sum_{k=0}^n\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}3^j= \\ = a_0\frac{1-3^{n+1}}{1-3}+2\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1-3^{k}}{1-3}= \\ = a_0\frac{1-3^{n+1}}{1-3}+\frac{2}{1-3}\bigg((n+1)-\frac{1-3^{n+1}}{1-3}\bigg)= \\ = \frac{1-3^{n+1}}{1-3}\bigg(a_0-\frac{2}{1-3}\bigg)+(n+1)\frac{2}{1-3}= \\ =\frac{3^{n+1}-1}{2}\bigg(a_0+1\bigg)-(n+1)$$

Comment: This is also a good method @Snoop. Thanks.

Comment: @itsCliffConnor: Just for future references, you do not need to ```@``` him. The user on whose post you commented will get a notification automatically.

Comment: Ok @ultralegend5385. Thanks. I'll keep that in mind.